# Looking For A Birds Of Prey Library

Tags: birds, sound-effects, library

I have found a ton of individual sites that have some good recordings here and there,

but anyone know of a solid library that has a good range of birds from owls to macaws, eagles, falcons, etc etc?

Ill toss some sites up that I have found:

http://soundbible.com/tags-bird-of-prey.html

http://www.audionetwork.com/sound-effects/living-creatures/birds/owls-and-birds-of-prey Youll have to sift through to find the good ones

http://www.sounddogs.com/results.asp?Type=1&CategoryID=1009&SubcategoryID=15

http://www.audiomicro.com/free-sound-effects/free-animal-sound-effects/free-bird-sound-effects same here, just another site that has a few – don’t know if they are good.

http://www.grsites.com/archive/sounds/category/10/?offset=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Macaulay Library](http://macaulaylibrary.org/) at Cornell licenses their recordings.

Comment: @JustinPearson Thanks Justin - great repository!

Answer (score 1):

Hi

If you're looking for birds, I'd recommend you the BBC Library. You can browse it online at:
https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundeffects/sound-effects-categories/sound-effects-birds.php
All birds and animals are categorized and labeled with the biological latin name.

If you only want the birds, just contact me. I can collect you the BBC bird sound only or the ones you like, up to almost 10'000 records.

If you are interested, send me an e-mail. You can contact me at: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundeffectscontact_e.php

Best

Guido

Comment: @GuidoHelbling Thanks for these - Ill check em out!